# How to interpret MPMediaItemCollection codes

Tags: ios, swift

When I choose to print out MPMediaItemCollection in my app I simply receive codes such as 0x17eb5d30.  Is anybody aware of how to get data from these random letters and numbers.  I am looking at hopefully retrieving the title of the song as well as the length of the song in seconds.

My code is here

```
@IBAction func pickSong(sender: AnyObject) {


    self.presentPicker(sender)


    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestView: playMusicViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! playMusicViewController
        DestView.selectedSong = MPMediaItemCollection()

    }


}


func presentPicker (sender:AnyObject) {

    let mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .Music)
    mediaPicker.delegate = self
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    presentViewController(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: {})

}
```

also the extension view controller

```
extension ViewController : MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
// must implement these, as there is no automatic dismissal

    func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {
        let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
        player.setQueueWithItemCollection(mediaItemCollection)
        player.play()
        println(mediaItemCollection)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: this "random" lets and numbers is a pointer to a memory address. You need to post your code so people can help you here. Edit your post to show what you are trying to do (code) and what you are encountering (error message) and we will be glad to help

Comment: edited, I am encountering no error, I simply need help translating what these letters and numbers represent.

Comment: How are you testing it? I run it in my iPhone and it runs fine

Comment: This does run fine, I am not attempting to fix an error, I am attempting to make sense of the codes that I receive when i use the println on the media collection.  As I would like to retrieve the song title to send to assign to a variable.  As code such as 0x17eb5d30 is basically useless to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number and letter you are seem is a pointer to an address in memory (normally not very useful for us) if you want to access details about the music you need to access the properties of the objects you received back for the picker. The example below show how to retrieve the title of the music selected:

```
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {
    let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
    player.setQueueWithItemCollection(mediaItemCollection)
    player.play()
    let item = mediaItemCollection.representativeItem
    let title = item.title
    println(title)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)  
}
```

I hope that help you!